# Inputting numerical data from .txt file to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a .txt file that contains many lines of data like this:

```
data[0]: a=123 b=234 c=3456 d=4567 e=123.45 f=234.56
```

The number of digits varies.
I am wondering how to extract only the numerical data from the line and put them in the worksheet. I have been searching a lot but they mainly deal with the csv format text.

I was thinking if I can use find function to locate every numerical data but it seems not possible because the number of digits is varying.

Please tell me if you have any ideas/suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Open your file in notepad and then do `replace all` few times, until your file has only digits, like this `123 234 4569`. Then replace spaces with commas. There we go - you have comma-delimited file. But if you want to do it programmatically, your question is not good enough. You would have to start writing your program and if it doesn't work out, ask the specific question

Comment: I am not allowed to alter the original text file. Do you mean there is a way to convert it to csv file programmatically? I get no idea in this one.

Comment: You can make a copy from original and work with that.Yes, programmatically you can do anything to this file

Answer (score 0):

1. Record a macro of the action: **Data → From Text**
2. Choose the file
3. Click **Delimited** and set the **Delimiters** to **Space** and set **Other** to `=`
4. In the preview screen select each column that contains a letter and click **Do not import column**
5. Review and modify macro code as needed

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the reply. Actually I am new to excel vba, may you further explain the steps? E.g. for the first step, I don't know what did it mean.

Comment: Try the method first manually using the *Data → From Text* option and see if it does what you want